# «Kuiri ĝis mola» kaj «bati ĝis morta»?

Tags: translation, prepositions

Ĉu oni povas traduki tiujn anglajn frazojn:

1. Cook until soft.
2. Hit until dead.

Kiel:

1. Kuiri ĝis mola.
2. Bati ĝis morta.

La [PoMEGo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/direktaj_rolvortetoj/ghis.html)
tian uzon ne mencias, sed eble ĝustas tamen?

(Mi komprenas, ke oni povas la frazojn alimaniere traduki, sed mi ankoraŭ volus
uzi tiun tradukon, se ĝi ĝustas.)

Answer (score 2):

`kuiri ĝis mola` ne ĝustas, kaj ankaŭ ne `bati ĝis morta`. En tiuj frazoj `ĝis` priskribas la [gradon/mezuron/staton](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/direktaj_rolvortetoj/ghis.html#i-dvf) rilate al ***la ago*** tial oni kutime uzas adverbon:

```
frapi ĝismorte
```

Oni povas ankaŭ uzi la -o formon de verbo, kiu do havos la saman subjekton:

```
frapi ĝis mortigo
```

Malĝusta estas la frazo <strike>frapi ĝis morta</strike> ĉar la subjekto de `frapi` ne estas tiu, kiu mortos kaj ankaŭ pro tio ke la frazo ne tutas, mankas -o vorto fine. Kontrolu [tion ĉi](https://tekstaro.com/?s=5f81c17e59230) por vidi la kutiman uzon.

Malgraŭ la malĝusteco, oni povus kompreni `frapi ĝis morta` kiel `ĝis kiam la frapanto mortas je laceco`.

Vi povas:

1. enkonduki la objekton:

   `kuiri ĝis moliĝo de la pasto / ĝis pastomoliĝo`
2. mencii la rezulton de la ago (en -o formo), se la objekto estas evidenta:

   `kuiri ĝis moliĝo`
3. mencii la agon (en -o formo) se la subjekto samas:

   `kuiri ĝis moligo` [moligas kaj kuiras la sama persono/maŝino]
4. priskribi la agon, se tio eblas. Ekzemple en kuirado:

   `bati ĝisŝaume`

Kelkaj ekzemploj el Tekstaro:

```
kaptos iun ajn taŭgan objekton kaj frapos ĝismorte. (Piron)

sed mi povus kisi vin ĝis mortigo (Kabe) [mortigas la kisanto]

kaj turmentos ĝin ĝismorte. (Engholm)
```

Comment: Vi pravas, sed tio ne respondas la demandon.

Comment: @Joffysloffy mi klopodis tion fari pli klare ĉi foje.

Comment: Jes, tio estas multe pli klara. Tamen ĉi tiu frazo ŝajnas malĝusta: “ĝis kiam la frapanto oni mortas je laceco”.

Comment: @Joffysloffy Korektita. Dankon.

Comment: Bone, nedankinde :).

Answer (score 2):

Temas pri kiel esprimi, ke la ago daŭru tiel longe, ke la objekto estas en la dezirata stato.

- Kuiru la terpomojn (tiel longe, ke ili estas molaj)
- La krimulo batis la viktimon (tiel longe, ke tiu mortis)

Laŭ tiu [artikolo en PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/direktaj_rolvortetoj/ghis.html), kiun vi jam referencis, oni uzas la prepozicio "ĝis" kune kun

- lokoj
- tempoj
- atingo de mezuro, grado, nivelo, stato

La origina demando temis pri tio, ĉu ŝanĝigo al iu stato similas atingon de io. Tian ŝanĝigon oni esprimas ekz. per la [translativa kazo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translativo) en kelkaj lingvoj, inkl. mia denaska lingvo, kaj ĉi tial mi povus akcepti esprimojn

- Kuiru la terpomojn ĝis molaj.
- La krimulo batis la viktimon ĝis morta.

Tamen komparu kun la jena frazo

- Mi farbis la muron blanka.

t.e. la muron ŝanĝiĝis al stato, kie ĝi estas blanka. Se la prepozicio "ĝis" montrus la translativon, oni dirus (kaj mi fakte preferus tion)

- Mi farbis la muron ĝis blanka.

sed en Esperanto oni komprenas, ke "blanka" estas priskribo de "la muro" (ĉar mankas la ideo de la translativo). Logike tiam oni esprimas la originalajn frazojn per sen "ĝis".

- Kuiru la terpomojn molaj.
- La krimulo batis la viktimon morta.

Se oni volas uzi "ĝis" kaj estas bone eksplicite montri la ŝanĝiĝon, oni uzu tiujn esprimojn de Eduardo Trápani.